# Get file name in a perticular cell

Tags: vba, filenames

Is there any way that using a VBA we can run a window select a file and when we click it the name should get copied without its extension (.txt) and should get copied to sheet "TEXT", cell AZ2.

I started with some code but its not working. Not sure how to do further.

```
Sub Main_Macro()
Dim fName As String, LastRowim As Long

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.adt")
If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try GetBaseName() method to get the name of file without extension.

Comment: Thank you but actually I am very new to vba coding. It would be very helpful for me if you could show me how to implement it in the code.

Comment: Can you brief the same in a code?? I need the file name to reflect in cell AZ2 of sheet "TEXT".

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim fName As String  ' Includes full path
    Dim fChosen As Integer
    Dim fNameFile As String  'Only the name of the file

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) 'open dialog box
            fd.Title = "Please select file" 'dialog Title
            fd.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" 'Path to initiate Dialog box
            'fd.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" 'alternate initial path
            fChosen = fd.Show
                    fd.Filters.Clear
                    'fd.Filters.Add "CSV files", "*.csv" 'add filters to only show this type of file
                    fd.Filters.Add "Text files", "*.txt" 'in this case only txt files will be selectable

         If fChosen <> -1 Then
             MsgBox "You Cancelled, nothing done!", vbInformation
         Else
            fName = Right$(fd.SelectedItems(1), Len(fd.SelectedItems(1)) - InStrRev(fd.SelectedItems(1), "\")) 'get full path of file, then remove anything prior to \ to get filename
            Position = InStr(fName, ".") 'get the position of the extension
            If Position > 0 Then Extension = Right(fName, Len(fName) - Position + 1) 'get the actual extension of the file
            fName = Replace(fName, Extension, "") 'remove that extenstion
            Sheets("TEXT").Range("AZ2").Value = fName 'enter the file name to your chosen range
        End If
End Sub
```